# Django: Javascript not loading extra rows

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have a page that allows a doctor to create a prescription. This page as a form that allows you to add as many rows as you want to add elements to your prescription. I will share with you the view and html template.

I replicated the exam same thing for creating another type of prescription (lab analysis).

This time, the button does not want to add more rows, even though I used the exact same code, and I will tell you exactly what breaks it, but I do not know how to fix it.

Here is the code for the first one (the one that works):

view:

```
@login_required
def createPrescription(request):
    [...] # ommited because unrelated
    drugs = Drug.objects.all()

    
    return render[...] # ommited because unrelated
```

HTML:

```
<!-- PAGE-HEADER END -->
            <form method="POST" id="presForm">
                {% csrf_token %}

                [...] # ommited because unrelated

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-title">Eléments de l'ordonnance</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                            <table id="myTable" class="table order-list">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Médicament</td>
                                        <td>Dosage</td>
                                        <td>Posologie</td>
                                        <td>Durée</td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="col-5">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                    <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Nom du médicament" type="text" name="medicament0">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-6">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <select class="form-control select2-show-search form-select" id="medicament-id0" name="listemedicament0">
                                                            <option value="0">Ou choisir de la liste</option>
                                                            {% for d in drugs %}   
                                                                <option value="{{ d.id }}">{{ d }}</option>
                                                            {% endfor %}
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="20mg" type="text" name="dosage0">
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="2 / j avant repas" type="text" name="posologie0">
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="7 jours" type="text" name="duree0">
                                        </td>

                                        <td><a class="deleteRow"></a>
                                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary " id="addrow" value="Ajouter élément" />
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                
                            </table>
                    </div>
                    
                        <div class="btn-list ms-auto my-auto">
                            <a href="{% url 'prescriptions' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-space mb-0">Annuler</a>
                            <button id="presBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-space mb-0">Soumettre</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--/Row-->
```

Now here is the code of the second one (the one that doesn't work):

view:

```
@login_required
def createLabRequest(request):
    
    exams = _ex.objects.all()

    
    return render[...] # ommited because unrelated
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- PAGE-HEADER END -->
            <form method="POST" id="presForm">
                {% csrf_token %}
                [...] # ommited because unrelated

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="card-title">Eléments d'analyses</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table id="myTable" class="table order-list">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Analyse</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="col-5">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Analyse" type="text" name="exam0">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <select class="form-control select2-show-search form-select" id="exam-id0" name="examlist0">
                                                        <option value="0">Ou choisir de la liste</option>
                                                        {% for e in exams %}   
                                                            <option value="{{ e.id }}">{{ e }}</option>
                                                        {% endfor %}
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </td>


                                    <td><a class="deleteRow"></a>
                                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary " id="addrow" value="Ajouter élément" />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            
                        </table>
                </div>
                    
                        <div class="btn-list ms-auto my-auto">
                            <a href="{% url 'labrequests' %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-space mb-0">Annuler</a>
                            <button id="presBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-space mb-0">Soumettre</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--/Row-->
```

Now the problem is this:

When I copied the code and renamed `{% for d in drugs %} <option value="{{ d.id }}">{{ d }}</option>` to `{% for e in exams %} <option value="{{ e.id }}">{{ e }}</option>` The button to add a new row stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem: the list contains some data that interferes with the loading of the JavaScript, to solve this, we need to make the following changes:

Add the following function to the MedicalExam model:

```
def examDisplay(self):
    display = ''.join(e for e in self.name if e.isalnum or e == ' ' or e == '-' or e == '/')
    return display
```

And in the HTML, we put:

```
{% for e in exams %} <option value="{{ e.id }}">{{ e.examDisplay }}</option>
```